# How do filter and convert unicode to integer in python

Tags: python

I have a unicode attribute which in the below format.  It can have a period or no event

```
x = P(1 s) or P(0.1 s) or P(0.01 s) or "No Event"
```

I need to check if x has a period and filter out only the number if it is period and convert it into an integer and export it to excel.  I know how to export to excel, but unable to filter.
If I use int(), it will give error if the attribute has not period, since they are only characters.

Comment: can you please specify the input and its expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if x == "No Event":
    # Handle no-event situation
    pass
elif x.startswith("P("):
    # extract the number
    s = x[2:].split()[0]
    if "." in s:
        # period present
        result = float(s)
    else:
        # period not present
        result = int(s)
else:
    # Handle unexpected input
    pass
```

Knowing the expected input precisely including all possible variations (allowed white space and so on) a shorter solution can be written using regular expression.